# How to install the Google Play Services library from a git submodule

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, git-submodules

Ok I know this question has been asked before. But the usual solution is to mark the "copy into the workspace" checkbox. (Which I believe is not even an option for me because even when I do that I get the same problem).

[image: I keep getting the red cross]

But that is not really a good solution to me, as I added the library as a submodule in my git repository and usually switch computers while developing (work and home). I would like the project to make a reference to it as a library project INSIDE the main project.

I cannot believe this can't be done. But I've tried lots of combinations and I'm almost giving up.

The funny thing is that as soon as I reference it as a project in the "Android" section of the Properties panel, it shows a green check mark. But as soon as I close the panel and then open it again, I get the red cross.. WTF!?

Comment: @Billthon how did you solve this problem?